# Build Android Core apps in eclipse

Tags: android

I downloaded some android projects from  [Android Git repositories](https://android.googlesource.com/) using git.

When i imported it in eclipse it has lots of errors, Can any one tell me how to build projects downloaded from Android Git repositories

Comment: You should also download the libraries for that project and add them to project's build path.

Comment: @BatuhanC when we clone project using git, it download every thing associated with that project right?

Comment: Yes but how about library projects? I also compile some of them like calculator and calendar. I needed to implement some library projects to build path. You should check the errors on imports, and see which library project you need.

Comment: @BatuhanC Just for curiosity, from where i get library ?

Comment: I googled the imports which gives errors and find the lib for that. I don't know any other easy methods :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the system core apps use some APIs marked as `@hide` in android framework. So you got some errors when set your project target to android official release SDK (which hide some APIs for some purposes).

In order to dismiss the errors, you need to add an external library `framework.jar` as a reference and set the reference to `Top` in `Java Build Path -> Order and export` of your project setting.

You can compile the AOSP to get the file `framework.jar`. The file will be located in `$aosp_dir/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates` after you compile AOSP.